# Build nodes from xpath

Tags: xslt

I have a source xml and from this source xml I like to select the nodes given by a path e.g. `/shiporder/item/title` and `/shiporder/shipto/name` from the sample source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<shiporder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" orderid="orderid1">
  <orderperson>orderperson1</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>name1</name>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>foo</title>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>bar</title>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

And I like to transform those nodes to certain target tree e.g. each `/shiporder/item/title` from the source xml should copied to `root/Customer/Name/Title` in the target xml tree. So my idea was to generate for each level in the source path a template and call this template from the preceding level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:func="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>     
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/shiporder"/>
    </root>

  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/shiporder">
    <Customer>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="shipto"/>
    </Customer>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/shiporder/item">
    <Name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
    </Name>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipto">
    <Address>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
    </Address>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/shiporder/item/title">
    <Title>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </Title>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/shiporder/shipto/name">
    <Street>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </Street>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There for I get a huge stylesheet if I have a huge list of source-paths. Has some one a more feasible idea to reach the target?

Comment: I would shorten the `<xsl:value-of select="text()" />` to `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` but other than that (rather cosmetic issue) I think the code is well used and well structured XSLT.

Comment: maybe  you write a program (another XSLT?) that will generate your working XSLT for you? Good luck.

Comment: You could also shorten `<xsl:template match="/shiporder/item/title">` to just `<xsl:template match="title">`. You don't need to specify the full path, unless the element occurs with different ancestors and you need to distinguish between them.